Questions about functions and their graphs
I just have a few questions about function analysis that have been confusing me ever since we started learning about it, hope someone can answer them.

When writing out a domain of a function, how do you do it with this specific interval notation?
Searching an answer for this online I only found people that wrote it as (e.g) (3,∞) but in class I always saw it written as [3, ∞] or ]3, ∞]. In the way my teacher writes it I don't understand which bracket is used to exclude or include a value.
Also, when do you use union or intersect to define the domain (e.g [-∞,3] U [4,∞])?
When studying end behaviors at infinity, do you always use the Hopital rule?
If we're looking at things such as the x intercepts of a rational function ( e.g (2x^2-8x-20)/(x^2-9) ) why can we simply ignore the denominator? For example in this case you would solve for when f(x) = 0, and therefore, 2x^2-8x-20, ingoring the denominator.
If x isn't always positive or negative for f(x), how do we know where the function is increasing or decreasing over its domain?
When we look at rational functions we make the denominator = 0 to find the vertical asymptote, but when the denominator is something a bit more complicated, such as 6x^2 - 17x +12, I was thinking you can simply do the qudratic formula to find the x values, but apparently on a video a guy was factorising the rational function (https://youtu.be/cjXseEPP9vc min 4.45)
What's the relation between f, f' and f''?


$3$ is easy : Suppose $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$ for some real $x$. We must have $g(x)\ne 0$ , otherwise $f/g$ is not defined at the particular point. So we can multiply with the number $g(x)$ and get $f(x)=0$. If on the other hand we have $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\ne 0$ , we cannot have $f(x)=0$ because the fraction would then always be $0$.

Voting to close for lack of focus. Try to contain posts to only a single question at a time, or a few closely related questions with more context and motivation.


Interval on wikipedia.  "When do you use union or intersect"  When it makes sense to.  2) Not always, there can be different situations with different techniques.  3) so long as ratio is defined (i.e. no division by zero) ratio is zero iff the numerator is zero.  4) Depends on what you've been taught, but calculus answers this easily.  5) factor however you are comfortable, doesn't matter.  6) calculus answers this


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The term “functional analysis” is generally reserved for a specific, and more advanced form of mathematics than what you seem to be asking about. You seem to have some basic questions about elementary algebra and set theory for the real numbers, at the level of what in the United States would be called a “pre-calculus” class, and also some questions about calculus.

This is one of those things that you need to ask your instructor about to know what notation they are using. It is likely that $]3, \infty]$ means the same thing as $(3,\infty]$. Asking when to use intersection or union is like asking when to use the word “and” versus the word “or.”
As far as I know there is no such thing as the “Hopital rule.” On the other hand, L'Hôpital's rule is used to evaluate indeterminate limits of the form $0/0.$
Because if $a/b=0,$ then this implies that $a$ must be 0, regardless of what $b$ is. See if you can think of a counterexample! (On the other hand $0/0$ is indeterminate, so to be precise you should in fact check the denominator.
Are you familiar with derivatives?
The quadratic formula and “factorizing” are both just different methods to find the zeros of a quadratic polynomial. Both work, although sometimes factorization may be too difficult.
$f’$ is the derivative of $f.$ This is a fundamental concept in calculus, and it should be one of the main things you learn about. There are plenty of videos on youtube and other websites which can teach you about this, but this website is not the appropriate place to ask such a broad question.


great this makes everything a lot clearer just


so do you use L'Hôpital's always to find the limits at positive and negative infinity? If not what do you use and how do you know you should use that?


yes i am, and my question was that since by looking at if x of f' is always negative or positive we can understand if a function is increasing/decreasing, what happens if there's variations where it goes up and down and how do i find them?


yes, i meant the relation between them such as what does an inflection point or maxima for f'' mean for f' and f


